# KML and MapView in iOS

Tags: ios, android-mapview, kml

I have a KML file with coordinates from all the countries (coordinates for polygons). I manage with Simple KML and KMLViewer from Apple to load the overlays on the map but I want my app to work offline. So actually I want to use a mapview which show nothing(like when you open the map app without internet connection). Can I force the mapview to stop loading of the maps?

Answer (score 0):

No, programatically, you can't stop that `MkMapView` tries to load the map data.

The user can disable "Mobile Data".

You have to create an own `MapView` which draws the polygons. Or you can use a lib like `RouteMe` that uses an own map view based on `OpenStreetMap`.

Comment: So do you have any other idea how to load only the polygons?